# Error : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException, How fix it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jetty

I have a problem with syntax SQL. When i `mvn jetty:run` then occur following error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "user" at
>   line 1, co lumn 14.
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknow
>   n Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source
>   )
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException
>   (Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Un
>   known Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown So
>   urce)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown So
>   urce)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at edu.java.spring.service.user.controller.CustomContextLoaderListener.c
>   reateTableNotExist(CustomContextLoaderListener.java:68)
>           at edu.java.spring.service.user.controller.CustomContextLoaderListener.c
>   reateTable(CustomContextLoaderListener.java:48)
>           at edu.java.spring.service.user.controller.CustomContextLoaderListener.c
>   ontextInitialized(CustomContextLoaderListener.java:36)

Here file `CustomContextLoaderListene` which encouter error:

```
package edu.java.spring.service.user.controller;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;

public class CustomContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hibernate shutdown database");
        try {
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:D:/PROJECTSPRING/userdb;shutdown=true");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("\n Spring-MVC application destroyed \n");
        super.contextDestroyed(event);

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("\n Spring-MVC application inited \n");
        try {
            createTable();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.contextInitialized(event);
    }

    public void createTable() throws SQLException{
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:D:/PROJECTSPRING/subjectdb;create=true");
            createTableNotExist(connection,"user", "create table user"
                    + "(username varchar(1000) primary key,"
                    + "password varchar(1000),birthday date,"
                    + "age integer,gender varchar(100))");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void createTableNotExist(Connection connection,
            String tableName,String createTableSQL) throws SQLException{
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null,tableName.toUpperCase(), null);
        if (rs.next()){
            System.out.println("Table" + rs.getString("TABLE_NAME") + "already exists");
            return;

        }
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(createTableSQL);
        System.out.println("\n\n executed" + createTableSQL + "\n\n");
        statement.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

"user" it is a built-in function in derby. Enter another table name and it should start work